# Specify Sequence of actions in Macro?

Tags: vba, excel, timing

I've written a series of macro's in a worksheet that work sequentially to download data through api and subsequently analyze and format the data.

My goal is to combine the six command buttons into one. but when I've done this, though I have only copied and pasted from one sub into another the results are different.

My guess is that the later commands (that are dependent on completion of previous steps) aren't waiting for the earlier commands to finish, in particular for the data to download.

Does this make sense to anyone more experienced with VBA or does vba code always evaluate sequentially and patiently?

Is there a command to add a time span between the execution of different pieces of the code?

Don't really need code help, just a guide to the command if it exists.

Thanks.

Comment: I know from my daily experience that by calling macros with `call` will enable VBA to wait for each process/maco to finish before starting the next. On the other hand, a rough but still a viable alternative would be calling the macros using `Application.Ontime`, based on estimates of time needed to perform the tasks. Hope this was on the subject.

Answer (score 1):

> Does this make sense to anyone more experienced with VBA or does vba code always evaluate sequentially and patiently?

Sequentially... Yes. Patiently? Definitely a big `NO`. Else we wouldn't have to use `DoEvents` :)

> Is there a command to add a time span between the execution of different pieces of the code?
>   Don't really need code help, just a guide to the command if it exists.

Like I mentioned above, you can either use `Doevents` or this `Wait` funciton which I use.

```
Sub Sample()
    MsgBox "Hello"

    Wait 5 '<~~ Wait for 5 seconds

    MsgBox "World"
End Sub

Private Sub Wait(ByVal nSec As Long)
    nSec = nSec + Timer
    While nSec > Timer
        DoEvents
    Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: Glad to be of help :)

Comment: isn't `call Macro1, call Macro`2 method a better sollution in your opinion ? as from what I can see, the timer is due to trigger the macro based on hard-coded values and these may be impaired by performance issues when ran on distinct machines or even distinct workloads of the same machine when/if  multi-tasking ?

Comment: @Takedasama: The macros are all together in one sub as mentioned in the question. See this part `My goal is to combine the six command buttons into one. but when I've done this, though I have only copied and pasted from one sub into another the results are different.`

Comment: Hey guys, I'll work out the best solution for my situation and come back and update you with the code. Thanks for taking interest.

Comment: I'm hard-headed and don't get this, If there were 6 buttons, then I suspect that these had attached 6 distinct macros. Now the user whats to only click once and run the whole code. But the problem is that when he merged the macro codes he got diffrent results, due to run-time priority. Thus why not creating a 7th macro, attach it to a new button, and then by this 7th macro call in order the other 6? I agree that hard-coded timing is a solution, but surely not the best. :)

Comment: @Takedasama: Asking questions if you have a doubt is not called being `hard-headed`. it's a good sign :) I do that all the time. Now the answer to your question is based on many probable things. If the macro after combining gave different results then it doesn't mean that we need to create a 7th macro. We can rectify that code. We just need to figure out what is not working. Now whether those 6 should be combined or not is an altogether different question which I guess you will have to direct at OP :)